# Get average time awake from array of sleep/wake stamps

Tags: php, datetime

I have been racking my brain trying to get this figured out...

I need to get an `AwakeDuration` into the following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-24 15:45:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-24 22:10:00
            [SleepDuration] => 6:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-23 15:25:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-23 23:00:00
            [SleepDuration] => 7:35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-22 12:45:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-22 23:00:00
            [SleepDuration] => 10:15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-21 13:00:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-21 21:00:00
            [SleepDuration] => 8:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-20 11:10:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-20 20:00:00
            [SleepDuration] => 8:50
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-19 09:00:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-19 16:30:00
            [SleepDuration] => 7:30
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-18 06:00:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-18 14:05:00
            [SleepDuration] => 8:05
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [WentToSleep] => 2019-07-17 05:15:00
            [WokeUp] => 2019-07-17 13:30:00
            [SleepDuration] => 8:15
        )
)
```

That is coming from the following bit of code:

```
$json = '[{"Sleep":"2019-07-24 15:45:00","Wake":"2019-07-24 22:10:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-23 15:25:00","Wake":"2019-07-23 23:00:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-22 12:45:00","Wake":"2019-07-22 23:00:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-21 13:00:00","Wake":"2019-07-21 21:00:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-20 11:10:00","Wake":"2019-07-20 20:00:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-19 09:00:00","Wake":"2019-07-19 16:30:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-18 06:00:00","Wake":"2019-07-18 14:05:00"},{"Sleep":"2019-07-17 05:15:00","Wake":"2019-07-17 13:30:00"}]';

$SleepWakeArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($SleepWakeArray AS $results) {

    $SleepDiff = (new DateTime($results['Sleep']))->diff(new DateTime($results['Wake']));
    $SleepDuration = $SleepDiff>h . ':' . str_pad($SleepDiff>i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $array[] = [
        'WentToSleep' => $results['Sleep'],
        'WokeUp' => $results['Wake'],
        'SleepDuration' => $SleepDuration,
    ];

}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to calculate a new value that is the `AwakeDuration` as one might call it.

So, I guess that I need to be using the time woke up `[1][Wake]` *(for example)* and the time that most recently went to sleep `[0][Sleep]`

Then do a `diff()` on `[1][Wake]` and `[0][Sleep]`

So something along the lines of this...

```
$WentToSleep = new DateTime('2019-07-24 15:45:00');  // `[0][Sleep]`
$WokeUp = new DateTime('2019-07-23 23:00:00'); // `[1][Wake]`
$Diff = $WentToSleep->diff($WokeUp);
$Duration = $Diff->h . ':' . str_pad($Diff->i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

But how to work out that logic within the code, has brainfried me today, hoping somebody can help me with this.

Comment: `$SleepDuration = $SleepDiff>h . ':' . str_pad($SleepDiff>i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);` sloppy coding... I'd say (if it wasn't the intermet who killed the dashes). Edit: raise your debug output level & output settings...you will get some useful informations.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a group break.

You loop over sorted data (mandatory!). Remember the last 'woke up' time for the next call using a variable (init with null). When it is not null, do the calculation (first entry can't have it, only if you preset the 'wokeup'). Update the 'wokeup' with the current one.

```
$wokeup = null;
foreach( ... as $data) {
    if (null !== $wokeup) {                    
        // calculate wake time "last wake" till "current sleep"
    }
    // update last woke up
    $wokeup = $data['wake'];
}
```